# Using DISTINCT with FIND_IN_SET

Tags: mysql, select, distinct, find-in-set

I want to select DISTINCT(p.ptype) at the same time I also want to get the c.category if p.ptype is not in the set of c.ptype

**Database Table: p**

```
id   ptype
1    Shirts
2    Cups
3    Shirts
4    Mugs
```

**Database Table: c**

```
id  category  ptype
1   Test      Pants, Shirts, TShirts
2   Test1     Cups, Mats, Rugs
```

The SQL command I tried is as follows

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ptype), IF(FIND_IN_SET(p.ptype, c.ptype), c.category,'') as category
FROM p, c
```

This outputs p.ptype which are in set twice. One time with a blank c.category field and one with filled c.category.

However the desired output is as follows

```
ptype    category
Shirts   Test
Cups     Test1
Mugs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing an explicit `LEFT JOIN` on the `ptype` from the `p` table being present in the CSV list in the `c` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ptype, COALESCE(c.category, '') AS category
FROM p
LEFT JOIN c
    ON FIND_IN_SET(p.ptype, c.ptype) > 0
```

In your original query, were doing a cross join.  This generates all possible combinations between the records of the two tables.  It would be difficult to arrive the correct answer using a cross join, so a left join is preferable.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle